# How to allow whitespace in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which allows only to enter integers and floats in a text box.
Regex Code:-

```
("^[0-9]*(?:[.][0-9]*|)$");
```

But it gives an error when the user enters whitespace at the beginning and end of the entered values. I want the user to allow spaces at the beginning and at the end as optional, so I changed the regex as below but it didn't work.

Note: Spaces may be spaces or tabs.

Test Case: User might enter:

```
"10","10.23"," 10","10 "," 10.23","10.23 "
```

Any number of  spaces are allowed.

```
("^(?:\s)*[0-9]*(?:[.][0-9]*|)$")
```

I am newbie with regex, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to use `(?:\s)`? Just so you know, it won't include the space in the match, if the string matches (just pointing it out). And why didn't you include the support for the whitespace at the end of the regex?

Comment: Because it is not working at beginning ,when it will work,i will add at the end also.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure you weren't testing the string " whatever " on the regex you provided :)

Comment: Do you need the whitespace at beginning and end? Why not get rid of it first, then regex? This is what `trim` does in many languages.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Javascript does not have a trim function in older browsers.

Comment: @lc. - I know that. Hence, the "in many languages".

Comment: `trim` is easy to add as a function or prototype to string - that's not too important

Comment: The [es5 shim/polyfill library](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js#L886) includes a `.trim` "fix".

Comment: Or, y'know, you could just let it fail and "remind" them numbers and periods are all that's allowed (no spaces!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a Regular Expression: `!isNaN(Number(textboxvalue.trim()))` would be sufficient.

Otherwise, try `/^\s{0,}\d+\.{0,1}\d+\s{0,}$/`. Test:

```
var testvalues = ["10","10.23"," 10","10 "," 10.23","10.23 ","10.24.25"];
for (var i=0;i<testvalues.length;i+=1){
  console.log(/^\s{0,}\d+\.{0,1}\d+\s{0,}$/.test(testvalues[i]));
}
//=> 6 x true, 1 x false
```

Comment: This would also allow inputs like `'+123e3'`.

Comment: Number('+123e3') is an integer, which according to the OP is allowed ;)

Comment: I need to do it in regex.It is need .

Comment: @KooiInc It may be valid in Javascript, but when it's sent to the server, that isn't necessarily an integer. I guess it depends on what the OP wants though

Comment: @KooiInc I was just pointing it out! If, for whatever reason, they **need** a number in an integer format and/or their server language doesn't support that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^\s*[0-9]*(?:[.][0-9]*|)\s*$/;
```

You don't have to wrap a single entity in a group to repeat it, and I have added a second zero-or-more-spaces at the end which is what you are missing to make it work.

Note: You have not posted the code you use to create the RegExp object, but if it is `new RegExp(string)`, remember to escape your backslashes (by doubling them):

```
var r = new RegExp("^\\s*[0-9]*(?:[.][0-9]*|)\\s*$");
```

---

Also, as @Blender suggests, this can be simplified to:

```
/^\s*[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?\s*$/;
```

Or, using `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
/^\s*\d*(?:\.\d*)?\s*$/;
```

Comment: @Asp_Newbie: Post your test case.

Comment: @lc. What do you mean by "wrap a single entity in a group to repeat it"? You mean this: `(?:\s)*`?

Comment: @ianpgall Yes. That you don't have to put parentheses `\s` in order to add the `*`

Comment: But `(?:\s)*` doesn't just group `\s`, it makes the regex forget it in the match. So that if you put in the string " whatever ", the match will be "whatever" (assuming they use it at the beginning and end. With your code, the match will be " whatever ", so I guess it depends on what the OP wants. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Blender
Check updation for test case.

Comment: @Asp_Newbie Post the code where you're using the regex because this should work.

Comment: @ianpgall That's not correct. You're confusing non-capturing groups with lookahead/lookbehind. Non-capturing groups simply do not create a backreference - it is as if what is in the group was not in a group - but it will match the whole thing. Lookahead, however does not store the lookahead portion in the match.

Comment: You can simplify the regex to `^\s*\d*(?:\.\d*)?\s*$`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses - Isn't that what the OP is using?

Comment: @ianpgall: Non-capturing groups just don't get captured. They allow you to group things like with regular groups, but without showing up in the result array when you use something like `.match()`. They don't get excluded from the results.

Comment: @Blender That's exactly what I said - it won't remember it in the match. So `\s*` is not the same as `(?:\s)*`. But I guess it depends on whether the OP is using `match` or just `test`. I don't know why, but I was focusing on `match`, and that's why I pointed out they aren't the "same".

Comment: @ianpgall Again, that's not correct. Try it yourself - everything will be returned in `match[0]` and there will be nothing in `match[1]` in either case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Anyways, the problem with all 3 regexes above, is that the backslahes need escaped. If you're using the `/ regex /` syntax, you don't need to. But the synax seems to be like `new RegExp("")`. I tested all 3 as is, and they don't work. As soon as I double escaped things, they work.